# Storing my dates as long (milliseconds) in SQLite: Can I use strftime(...)?

Tags: sqlite, strftime

I'm storing my dates in SQLite in a column of data type INTEGER. I'm storing the milliseconds since 1970.

Eg:

```
  date (long)       other columns ...
  -----------------------------------------
   1407297600000       ...
   1407211200000       ...
   1407124800000       ...
```

My question is: **how can I use strftime() under this circumstances?**
If not, I should use TEXT as the column type??

Running this:

```
 select strftime('%Y-%m', date) from my_table;
```

Is throwing nonesense stuff:

```
  strftime('%Y-%m', date)
  -----------------------------------------
   1968-19
   1968-19
   1968-19
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you tell it otherwise, `strftime()` thinks those numbers are Julian day values - very different from Unix epoch milliseconds.

You'll want to convert to seconds, and tell `strftime()` these are Unix epoch numbers:

```
select strftime('%Y-%m', date / 1000, 'unixepoch');
```

See the **Modifiers** section in the [SQLite Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) docs.

Comment: If I'm still in time to redesign the schema, what would you use to store the date? what is the best practice? would you store seconds instead of milliseconds?

Comment: It really depends on your application. If your language / app / library of choice likes Epoch milliseconds, and the conversion is cheap, you're fine.

Comment: Is the conversion cheap? in this case the conversion is just date/1000